# How to identify numeric values in a dataframe column with more than 10+ digits using pyspark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to identify numeric values from a column. I did the below option to achieve the same.

But for '7877177450' it is showing as non-numeric.According to my scenario the ID's can be number with 10+ digits also.

How to make that work?

```
values = [('695435',),('7877177450',),('PA-098',),('asv',),('23456123',)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(values,['ID',])
df.show()
df = df.withColumn("Status",F.when((col("ID").cast("int").isNotNull()) ,lit("numeric")).otherwise(lit("non-numeric")))
df.show()

+----------+
|        ID|
+----------+
|    695435|
|7877177450|
|    PA-098|
|       asv|
|  23456123|
+----------+

+----------+-----------+
|        ID|     Status|
+----------+-----------+
|    695435|    numeric|
|7877177450|non-numeric|
|    PA-098|non-numeric|
|       asv|non-numeric|
|  23456123|    numeric|
+----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast to `long` instead:

```
df2 = df.withColumn("Status", F.when((F.col("ID").cast("long").isNotNull()), F.lit("numeric")).otherwise(F.lit("non-numeric")))
```

`int` has a maximum value of 2147483647, so it cannot handle values greater than this, and you'll get null.

Or you can use a regular expression:

```
df2 = df.withColumn("Status",F.when(F.col('ID').rlike('^(\\d)+$'), F.lit("numeric")).otherwise(F.lit("non-numeric")))
```